# make an application ask for password applescript

Tags: passwords, applescript

I'm trying to write an AppleScript Code which makes Firefox ask me for a password when I open it. This is what I got, but somehow it doesn't work:

```
on activate
display dialog "Please enter your password" buttons {"Cancel", "Okay"} default answer "" default button 2
set x to text returned
if x is "Password" then
    tell application "Firefox"
        activate
        reopen
    end tell
else
    say "please try again"
end if
end activate
```

I also need to know where to save the Script, when it is correct. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Why? A script cannot prevent users launching applications. Access permissions are enforced by the OS on a per-user account basis. If you need to restrict which apps can be launched, create a new standard user account (or use the existing guest user account if it's for anyone to access) and use the Parental Controls option in System Preferences' Accounts pane to configure it as required.

Answer (score 0):

There was an error in the `set x to text returned`. It needs to know what dialog you're referring to. See below.

```
on activate
set passwordRequest to display dialog "Please enter your password" buttons {"Cancel", "Okay"} default answer "" default button 2
set x to text returned of passwordRequest

if x is "Password" then
    tell application "Firefox"
        activate
        reopen
    end tell
else
    say "please try again"
end if
end activate
```

Comment: Okay thanks. Now where do I save the script, and which extension do I use?

Comment: Assuming you're using Script Editor, save it wherever you like as an "Application". It'll handle the extension part for you.

Comment: That didn't work. When I clicked on Firefox, it still opened without asking me for a password. When I tried opening it with Speech Recognition, it didn't open at all.

Comment: _"A client has asked me to build and install a custom shelving system. I'm at the point where I need to nail it, but I'm not sure what to use to pound the nails in. [Should I use an old shoe or a glass bottle?](http://weblogs.asp.net/alex_papadimoulis/408925)"_

Comment: See also [my previous response](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31292054/make-an-application-ask-for-password-applescript#comment50581694_31292054).

Answer (score -1):

Heres how paste this in ur script editor then save as whatever the name you want but also save as a application when you do that u can change the app log to what ever you want then run the

```
on run
    set defaultanswer to display dialog "Please enter a passphrase to use this script." default answer "" with icon stop buttons {"Cancel", "Continue"} default button "Continue" with hidden answer
    set x to text returned of defaultanswer

    if x is "ANY PASSWORD U WANT" then
        tell application "ANY APPLICATION U WANT"
            activate
            reopen
        end tell
    else
        say "please try again"
    end if
end run
```